# Synthesizing a boolean expression based on several constraints

Tags: z3, boolean-logic, solver, boolean-expression, smt

What I need is pretty straight-forward, I'm looking for a tool/library that gets several
constraints in a format like this:

1. `{"vars": {a=2, b=1, c=3}, "eval": "False"}`
2. `{"vars": {a=1, b=1, c=2}, "eval": "True"}`
3. `{"vars": {a=1, b=2, c=1}, "eval": "True"}`

And then synthesize a boolean expression for me based on predefined symbols:

- `Symbols: ["between variables": ['<=', '>=', '<', '>', '==', '!='], "between expressions": ['and', 'or']]`

I need only one solution for this system; for instance, one can be

- `a == b or b == c or a == c`

I've been looking into Z3 library features but couldn't find anything useful. Please do inform me if you know about an appropriate tool.

Answer (score 1):

Program synthesis is a very active area of research; and the quality of the programs you'll get really depends on what sort of program templates you want to use. An SMT solver will most likely not give you the kind of programs that you're looking for out-of-the-box, although they *will* work.

Here's how I'd code your current problem: I'd use an uninterpreted function and add the "test-cases" as constraints. Like this:

```
(declare-fun f (Int Int Int) Bool)
(assert (not (f 2 1 3)))
(assert      (f 1 1 2))
(assert      (f 1 2 1))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

When I run this, z3 says:

```
sat
(
  (define-fun f ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Int)) Bool
    (ite (and (= x!0 2) (= x!1 1) (= x!2 3)) false
      true))
)
```

If you read the output, you'll see that it essentially synthesized the following program:

```
   if (a == 2) && (b == 1) && (c == 3)
   then False
   else True
```

Is this correct? Absolutely. Is this really what you wanted it to do? Most likely not. But out-of-the box you'll not get anything better from an SMT solver.

For synthesizing cool programs using SMT based technologies, see, for instance, Emina Torlak's research. Here's a good paper to start with: http://synapse.uwplse.org